# Beginner error: TypeError: Molecularbiology.__init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and at the basic level. I'm trying to create new subclasses with `__init__` override but it gives me positional errors when inheriting from the parent class. Can you please help me in understanding this. I tried fixing my indentation and playing around.

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Molecularbiology.__init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

```
class Employee:

    raise_amount = 1.08
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@gmail.com'
       

class Developer(Employee):

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang): #inheritance
        super().__init__(first, last, pay) 
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang

class Molecularbiology(Employee):

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, mol_bio): #inheritance
         super().__init__(first, last, pay, prog_lang) 
         self.mol_bio = mol_bio


dev_1 = Molecularbiology(' Kubri', 'Lyreco', 100000, 'Python', 'RNASeq')
dev_2 = Molecularbiology('Vikki', 'Suomalainen', 50000, 'Javascript', 'Microscopy')

print(dev_1.email)
print(dev_1.prog_lang)
print(dev_1.mol_bio)
```

I want to include the subclass while inheriting arguments from the parent class

Comment: Why are you passing a programming language to `Molecularbiology()`?  The class has no defined parameter for which that value makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do exactly. Firstly, instead of `Molecularbiology`, I think you mean `MolecularBiologist`. Now, are `MolecularBiologist`s supposed to have a `prog_lang` attribute? That'd explain why you're passing one in, but then, why doesn't the `__init__` take it as a parameter, and why doesn't `Employee.__init__` do anything with it? I could go on, but it'd be better for you to explain. Check out [ask] and try to make a [mre], explaining what exactly the code is supposed to do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your code isn't structured correctly, so what might be best is if you did some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), i.e. walk through your code slowly and explain each part. If this is homework, you might talk to your instructor/TA/peer. Related to that, see [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341).

Comment: Passing the arguments intended for `Employee.__init__` to `MolecularBiology.__init__` doesn't automatically ensure that they get passed to `Employee.__init__`. See https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on defining `__init__` methods for the classes in a multiple-inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The naming of the variables makes hard to understand what you want to do and thus to give you a more general answer.

To answer your exact question, `Molecularbiology()` requires 4 explicit arguments: the `self` argument should not be explicitly passed when you instantiate the class, and the `__init__` method has 4 arguments if you exclude the `self`. You need to remove one of the instantiation argument (not very clear which one) to fix this.

You will have another error then, because the line                   `super().__init__(first, last, pay, prog_lang)` implies that the `prog_lang` variable is available in the scope (ie it is an argument of encompassing `__init__` method), and it is not. Fixing this error depends on what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Thanks Amiel. As you suggested I played around by adding/removing some parameters from __init__ method and it worked. I wanted to have skills for my employee class and now it works. Thanks, community for the help and comments